# What is the purpose of 'link rel=next' in WordPress, and why is it causing a 404 error on category pages?

Tags: html, wordpress

Why does this code：

```
<link rel="next" href="https://gameonebet.com/page/2/" />
```

also exist on the category page, but when I click on the next page it always shows a 404 error page? Is there an error in the template code?

I'm completely at a loss and can't pinpoint the cause.